# E: Package 'xgraph' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, dpkg

I want to install `ns2` on my Ubuntu 12.04. As usual am trying to install some essential software before installing it. I tried to install:

```
sudo apt-get install perl xorg-dev g++ xgraph libxt-dev libx11-dev libxmu-dev
```

And I get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package xgraph is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'xgraph' has no installation candidate
```

What should I do?

I ve searched everywhere online for a solution but got none.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you enabled the `universe` repository? if not, do so and then run `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

The package `xgraph` is available on [Universe repositories for 12.04](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/universe/base/xgraph)

> The **main** component contains applications that are free software, can be freely redistributed and are fully supported by the Ubuntu team. & The **universe** component is a snapshot of the free, open-source, and Linux world.

1. First enable repository,

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe"
   ```
2. **Update** to aware apt for your repositories changes

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Then install package by `sudo apt-get install xgraph`